# Why did not Urmila accompany Lakshmana?

Tags: ramayana

Just like Sita accompanied Lord Rama during "vanavasa", were it not the dharma of Urmila to accompany Lakshmana?

Comment: In the samvad between Urmila and Lakshamana before he left, he told urmila to take care of the their three mothers as she was the eldest Daugter-in-law left in their family,she has to bear all the duties.

Comment: But there are the other daughters- in- law with their husbands (Bharatha & Shatrughna) who are equally responsible to bear all duties.

Comment: Urmila was the closest person to sita and was elder to all other Daughter-in-law's

Comment: It was dharma of sita also to serve the family of rama , but she broke that dharma, but Urmila followed her dharma.

actually husband and family both are important , so this was conflicting scenario.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://greatramayana.com/ramayan-characters/urmila-57) link gives details about Laxman's wife Urmila and it also states that she was serving Lord Ram and Laxman's parents, as the eldest Daughter-in-Law of their family after Lord Ram Laxman and Godess Sita left for the forest life (vanvasa) of 14 years.

> According to Ramayana, when Lakshman was leaving for the forest with
>   lord Rama, Urmila was ready to accompany him. But, Lakshmana hesitates
>   and advises her to stay back to take care of her "in laws".He also
>   states that he cannot take care of her in the forest as he will be
>   busy serving his brother and apologizes to her. Urmila agrees and
>   remains a devoted wife for fourteen years until her husband returned

Source [Wikipedia (Urmila)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urmila_%28Ramayana%29)

Comment: The Wikipedia article is simply wrong about the Ramayana mentioning any such discussion between Laskhmana and Urmilla.  That's why you should be wary of relying on Wikipedia.

Comment: Not sure where I read it.. Urmila was in  sleep state most of the 14 years.

Comment: @Narasimham how is it possible? and why would she ignore her mother's- in-law and sleep while her husband is away.

Comment: May be heard it long ago, yes,,,never believed it though.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan what r ur precious views about this article http://devdutt.com/articles/indian-mythology/ramayana/lakshmans-wife-goes-to-sleep.html He has written many books on Hinduism. Can we believe in this article and his other books, articles, videos etc.?

Comment: @YDS No, to use an American expression, I trust Devdutt Pattanaik as far as I can throw him.  I used to read his books a lot when I was little, but then as I learnt more about Hinduism I realized how much inaccuracy and creative license there was in his works.  This was further confirmed when I emailed him a few years ago, pointing out an error he made in one of his books.  He emailed me back, saying that Hindu scripture was just written by Brahmins in order to control the rest of society, so it doesn't matter if he misrepresents Hindu scripture.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan thank you very much for your valuable time. Shall keep these points in mind while reading his books.