# Why did Sita go to the forest with Rama?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama, dharma, sita

While Rama was going to the forest, Sita also went to the forest **without any second thought** as far as I know;

Why did Rama allow her to do it? **Did any discussion happen between Rama and Sita to make such decision** (allowing Sita to forest)?

**Is there any rule for the wife to follow husband even in difficult situations** if there is an option for the wife to stay without difficulty?

In concise: *is it allowed for the wife to stay in rich and comfortable place while husband is staying in poor place or difficult situations?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Dharma forces Lakshman to leave his wife and accompany Lord Rama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22377/what-dharma-forces-lakshman-to-leave-his-wife-and-accompany-lord-rama)

Comment: Not a duplicate, because the questioner actually wants to ask about whether a wife can remain in fortunes while husband is in difficult situations.The context from Ramayana can be only taken as an example but the correct answer should come from any rules or patni dharmas mentioned in any scriptures.

Comment: " If such rule exists, then how can Lakshmana..." is a different question together and already asked. Please remove that portion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Did any discussion happen between Rama and Sita to make such decision (allowing Sita to forest)?**

Yes, there happened a very long discussion on this.

The discussion was so long that it is mentioned in **5 Sargas of Ayodhya Kanda of Valmiki Ramayan**:

- [Sarga 26](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga26/ayodhya_26_frame.htm)
- [Sarga 27](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga27/ayodhya_27_frame.htm)
- [Sarga 28](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga28/ayodhya_28_frame.htm)
- [Sarga 29](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga29/ayodhya_29_frame.htm)
- [Sarga 30](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga30/ayodhya_30_frame.htm)

---

**Why did Sita go to the forest with Rama?**

This is what Sita herself told Rama in this regard:

> आर्य पुत्र पिता माता भ्राता पुत्रः तथा स्नुषा |
>
> स्वानि पुण्यानि भुन्जानाः स्वम् स्वम् भाग्यम् उपासते || [२-२७-३](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga27/ayodhyasans27.htm#Verse3)
>
> O son of a noble monarch father, mother, brother, son or daughterinlaw (everybody) experiences the merit (of their past deeds) and receives what is due from destiny. ~[English translation source](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=2&field_sarga_value=27&field_sloka_value=3)
>
> भर्तुर् भाग्यम् तु भार्या एका प्राप्नोति पुरुष ऋषभ |
>
> अतः चैव अहम् आदिष्टा वने वस्तव्यम् इति अपि || [२-२७-४](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga27/ayodhyasans27.htm#Verse4)
>
> A wife alone, O best of men shares the destiny of her husband. I am also therefore, ordered to dwell in the forest. (a command to you is a command to me). ~[English translation source](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?field_kanda_tid=2&language=dv&field_sarga_value=27&field_sloka_value=4&)

---

Related

[What Dharma forces Lakshman to leave his wife and accompany Lord Rama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22377/what-dharma-forces-lakshman-to-leave-his-wife-and-accompany-lord-rama/22417#22417)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there was detailed conversation.

maa sita basically said " I'm going to forest. If you want, you follow me"

Sita : "Rama, When I was born, they calculated my jatakam and said I have vanvaas in my future."

Sita : "Tell me what is heaven & hell"

Rama : "Swarg lok, Indra, pleasures. Narak lok, Yama, pain"

Sita : "Looks like you didn't study properly. You should have asked me back 'heaven & hell according to who'. Where you are Rama, that is heaven for me. Where you are not, that is hell for me."

More dialogue happened. Can post source later.

Comment: Yeah, waiting for the source...

Comment: Valmiki Ramayana-AyodhyaKanda-Sarga 26to30 might be useful as valid sources...